# PROGRAMAÇÃO FUNCIONAL: Função recursiva para calcular o resto da divisão entre dois números inteiros positivos em ELM

Tags: recursão, programação-funcional, elm

Olá, estou com dificuldades para fazer uma função recursiva que passe como resultado o resto da divisão de dois números inteiros em ELM. Eu consegui realizar a função sem recursão como mostrado no print abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas preciso aplicar uma função recursiva que traga o mesmo resultado ! Poderiam me auxiliar ?! A  linguagem utilizada é o ELM derivada de Haskell !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ponto chave para construir a função recursiva neste caso é empregar a operação de subtração:

```
restoPosRec dividendo divisor =
if dividendo == 0 || divisor == 1 then 0
else if dividendo < divisor then dividendo
else restoPosRec (dividendo - divisor) divisor
```

Obs.: Sugiro que na função iterativa da pergunta (`restPos`) altere-se a linha `else if divisor > dividendo then 0` por `else if divisor > dividendo then dividendo`, pois caso contrário a função sempre retorna `0` se na chamada inicial o dividendo for menor que o divisor. Por exemplo em `restoPos 2 3 = 0`, quando deveria ser `restoPos 2 3 = 2`.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo ! Sua resposta foi sucinta e direta

Comment: Obrigado @FehlbergSkady!